# Third level accordion will not open css

Tags: html, css

I am building an accordion three level menu. I have zero knowledge in writing this other than what I've read through blogs on this site and others and copied from existing accordions.

I was able to build a successful two level accordion but I cannot post two separate two level accordions on our sharepoint site - they both cancel each other out and won't open.

So I combined them and built a three level accordion but I cannot get the third level to open. To simplify I cut down the amount of info from the html and removed sensitive links.

Can anyone assist please?

```css
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="nav.js"></script> -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");
      
      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }
    
    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
</script>

<style>
 ol, ul, li {
  padding: 0;
}

menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; } 

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }


h1 { font-family: 'Merienda', 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 2.95em; line-height: 1.7em; margin-bottom: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -0.03em; color: #675d90; text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.65); text-align: center; }


#w { display: block; width: 740px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 45px; }


/* nav menu styles */
#nav { 
  display: block; 
  width: 280px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

#nav li { }

#nav > li > a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 16px 18px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;
  background-color: #343434;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#214c7c), to(#284e7a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #214c7c, #284e7a);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #214c7c, #284e7a);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #214c7c, #284e7a);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #214c7c, #284e7a);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #214c7c, #284e7a);
}
#nav > li > a:hover, #nav > li > a.open { 
  color: #e9e9e9;
  border-bottom-color: #384f76;
  background-color: #6985b5;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6985b5), to(#456397));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
}

#nav li ul { display: none; background: #4a5b78; }

#nav li ul li a { 
  display: block; 
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e3e7f1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: #394963;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
   
    <nav>
      <ul id="nav">
       <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Member</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>ATAAPS</span></a>
             <ul>
             <li><a href="www.google.com"><span>LOG IN</span></a></li>
      <li class='last has-sub'><a href="www.google.com"><span>google</span></a><li>            
            </ul>
  </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Supervisor</span></a>
       <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>ATAAPS</span></a>
  <ul> 
             <li><a href="www.google.com"><span>LOG IN</span></a></li>
      <li class='last has-sub'><a href="www.google.com"><span>Traumatic Injury</span></a><li>     
 </ul>
</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, i made it rather quickly. But you could just assign an attribute to each one.

```js
$('.header').click(function(){
  var accordId = $(this).attr('accordID');
  $('.content').slideUp();
    $('.content[accordID="' + accordId + '"]').slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  background: #ebebeb;
  border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
.header {
  padding:10px;
  background:#666;
  color:#fff;
}
.content {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="header" accordID="1"> Header </div>
    <div class="content" accordId="1"> Content </div>
  </div>
    <div class="accordion">
    <div class="header" accordID="2"> Header 2 </div>
    <div class="content" accordId="2"> Content 2</div>
  </div>
      <div class="accordion">
    <div class="header" accordID="3"> Header 3 </div>
    <div class="content" accordId="3"> Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple jquery 3 level Accordion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34652439/1384591

and one pure css multi level accordion:

https://medium.com/@AlexDevero/multi-level-sliding-accordion-only-with-css-1adc6ca6de16

PS. Regarding your code, I see 2 issues: the html code doesn't validate, and the javascript is applied only to  $("#nav > li > a") that translates to the first level of links.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I will take a look at the html.

Comment: welcome, good luck! here is the code for the second solution: https://github.com/alexdevero/CSS-sliding-multi-level-accordion